# devise encrypted_password requried error when running all tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I'm using devise on a Rails 3.1 project and when I run my rspec tests for user separately they pass with no problems.

```
rspec spec/model/user_spec.rb
```

However, if I run all my tests using `rake` then it fails on these four user related tests

```
  describe "validation" do
    context "when user is from google" do
      before do
        @user = User.new(email: "example@gmail.com")
        @user.authentications.build(provider: "google", uid: "1234")
      end

      it "should be valid" do
        @user.valid?.should be_true
      end

      it "should save" do
        @user.save.should be_true
      end
    end

    context "when user is from twitter" do
      before do
        @user = User.new(email: nil)
        @user.authentications.build(provider: "twitter", uid: "1234")
      end

      it "should be valid" do
        @user.valid?.should be_true
      end

      it "should save" do
        @user.save.should be_true
      end
    end
  end
```

These tests focus in on when a user is signing up using either google or twitter.

If I put a debugger in the test I can manually type

```
(rdb:1) @user.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000ca98e98 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "example@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, admin: nil, given_names: nil, surname: nil, dob: nil, address: nil, suburb: nil, state: nil, country: nil, phone: nil, interests: nil, venue_manager: nil, nickname: nil, data_entry: nil>, @messages={}>
(rdb:1) @user.valid?
false
(rdb:1) @user.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000ca98e98 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "example@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, admin: nil, given_names: nil, surname: nil, dob: nil, address: nil, suburb: nil, state: nil, country: nil, phone: nil, interests: nil, venue_manager: nil, nickname: nil, data_entry: nil>, @messages={:encrypted_password=>["can't be blank"]}>
(rdb:1)
```

For some reason I'm being prompted for a password. I have the following method in my user model.

```
  def password_required?
    authentications.empty? && (!persisted? || password.present? || password_confirmation.present?)
  end
```

If I put my debugger in there then I can prove that this will return false, I still get the error though.

**UPDATE**

Added the following test for google signed up users

```
  it "should not require a password" do
    @user.send(:password_required?).should be_false
  end
```

These users don't require a password. This test passes both when I run the user_spec alone and when I run it all together using `rake`. The others tests still fail when running using `rake` as they still fail validation.

**UPDATE**

Here is the top of my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications    
  has_many :created_venues, foreign_key: :created_by_id, class_name: "Venue"
  has_many :manages
  has_many :venues, :through => :manages    
  has_many :events

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  default_scope :order => "given_names"

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_protected :admin
  attr_reader :venue_tokens
  <snip>
```

**UPDATE: Looking at validations on User**

```
 > p User._validate_callbacks.map(&:raw_filter)
[:validate_associated_records_for_authentications, :validate_associated_records_for_created_venues, :validate_associated_records_for_manages, :validate_associated_records_for_venues, :validate_associated_records_for_events, #<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x000000087a54b0 @attributes=[:email], @options={:if=>:email_required?}>, #<ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator:0x000000089a5260 @attributes=[:email], @options={:case_sensitive=>true, :allow_blank=>true, :if=>:email_changed?}, @klass=User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, admin: boolean, given_names: string, surname: string, dob: date, address: string, suburb: string, state: string, country: string, phone: string, interests: text, venue_manager: boolean, nickname: string, data_entry: boolean)>, #<ActiveModel::Validations::FormatValidator:0x000000089fe518 @attributes=[:email], @options={:with=>/\A[^@]+@([^@\.]+\.)+[^@\.]+\z/, :allow_blank=>true, :if=>:email_changed?}>, #<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x00000008a874f8 @attributes=[:password], @options={:if=>:password_required?}>, #<ActiveModel::Validations::ConfirmationValidator:0x00000008abb5c8 @attributes=[:password], @options={:if=>:password_required?}>, #<ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator:0x00000008ae66d8 @attributes=[:password], @options={:allow_blank=>true, :minimum=>6, :maximum=>128}>]
```

Comment: Devise only validates `password` and `password_confirmation`, not `encrypted_password` directly. You can add a test `user.send(:password_required?).should be_true` . If this test passes, there must be some other validations.

Comment: password_required should be false for google & twitter signed in users. I've updated this test in my question. So looks like I've been looking in the wrong place. For some reason it's still failing validation when running all the tests together.

Comment: You need to show more of your user model, like scorix said, there is no default presence validator on `encrypted_password` from Devise. Something added one (either you or another gem).

Comment: guessing from the code that you are implementing omniauth for google and twitter authentication. Check https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/1338738

Answer (score 0):

There must be a `PresenceValidator` on attribute `encrypted_password`.

Run this in console to list all the validate callbacks of `User` model:

```
# active_record 4
p User.send(:get_callbacks, :validate).instance_variable_get(:@chain).map(&:filter)

# active_record 3
p User._validate_callbacks.map(&:raw_filter)
```

Find the validator and remove it.